# using more let variables in the module shall cause memory issue in xquery?

Tags: xquery

In my code,

I have the following snippet

```
if($node/@attr) 
 then fn:data($node/@attr) 
 else ""
```

Now for performance improvement I wanted to change it as

```
let $attr := $node/@attr
 return if($attr) 
        then fn:data($attr) 
        else ""
```

Which one will be good? First or Second

Using more let variables in a function or in the module will cause any memory issue or any performance degradation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It depends

This heavily depends on the XQuery implementation you choose: on one engine, `let` expressions might be more costly than re-evaluating the expression, on others it might be the other way round. This is also very likely to depend on the amount of data returned. Large amounts will require more memory, but also be more expensive to evaluate. Other engines might use a streaming approach that only requires constant memory anyway...

All in all, you have to try and benchmark both versions to get a feeling what's going on. If your query engine outputs a query plan, study this whether the optimizer does not change your query anyway to something completely different. In the end, you will probably realize it doesn't make a (noteworthy) difference in most cases, anyway: stick with the version of code that's better to read and understand, and less likely to involve programming errors.

### Query optimizers

If there is a reasonable query optimizer, better don't do such minor optimizations anyway, most of the time the optimizer knows better than the developer (especially, if the input differs from time to time).

### Optimizing this specific query

In your very special example, `fn:data($node/@attr)` should be fine, anyway for most use cases, otherwise apply `string(...)` instead or simply cast to a string `fn:string($node/@attr)`.

Comment: Thank you so much. In the same way, is it good idea to have multiple global variables in a module?

Comment: If you have only a few, you'll probably never care about it. If you're generating code with hundreds or thousands of variables, start considering consequences; otherwise you won't have to care, especially if you're using the data retrieved anyway. Put more effort in reasonable XPath expressions matching the way your XQuery engine works (for example, some axes and kinds of predicates will be much more expensive than others), which often results in notable performance improvement. Putting a variable here or there will usually not be measurable at all.